# How to select rows with the latest time for each date within the last 30 days from now

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Imagine a table with field '**datetime**'. Example rows:

- **2017-01-27 13:06:02**
- 2017-01-27 05:13:14
- **2017-01-23 22:13:56**
- **2017-01-26 14:02:09**
- 2017-01-23 13:26:12
- ...

I need to get * from the bold lines, BUT WITHIN the last 30 days from now...

In other words, rows with the max date in the last 30 days.

30 rows in total in each case, assuming every day has at least one row...

Comment: Why those 3 rows?  Do you mean the rows with the latest time for each date?

Comment: Yes @SteveSmith, exactly that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `group by` the date part of datetime and get the max for each day.

```
select max(`datetime`) 
from tablename
where `datetime` >= date(now())-interval '30' day
group by date(`datetime`)
```

To get all the fields from the table for such rows, use

```
select * from tablename where `datetime` in (
select max(`datetime`) 
from tablename
where `datetime` >= date(now())-interval '30' day
group by date(`datetime`)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, @vkp, but I need all the fields of the table in each case, not only the datetime. Do you have any clue?

Answer (score 1):

vkp's answer is basically correct, although there's no need for subquery to select the final result from - you can just put other columns straight into your query, up to something like this:

```
select *, max(datetime) 
from tablename
where datetime >= date(now())-interval '30' day
group by date(datetime);
```

Ah, and that works for joins too.

The other thing I'd change to address the goal more precise, is:

```
max(time(datetime))
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from your_table
where datetime between sysdate and sysdate-30

Comment: That is incorrect because it would get ALL the rows with datetime within last 30 days. And I need only the rows whose datetime is maximum EACH DAY within that 30 last days... I.e., 30 rows in total if every day had at least one row...