# Query for get lastupdate datetime in redudant date table

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I want to get lastupdate datetime order by updateTime but prevent for redundant date in my output

desired result

```
2021-06-25 15:46:57
2021-06-26 15:48:52
2021-06-27 17:11:52
2021-06-28 17:17:33
2021-06-29 15:16:29
```

I tried this

```
SELECT t.updateHistoryID, t.updateTime 
FROM web_historyupdate t 
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT updateHistoryID, max(updateTime) as maxdate 
                FROM web_historyupdate 
                GROUP BY updateHistoryID ) tm 
            ON t.updateHistoryID =tm.updateHistoryID 
        AND t=tm.maxdate
```

Comment: It looks like you want the maximum datetime per date. "Maximum" translates to `MAX` in SQL, "per" transates to `GROUP BY`. Does this help?

Comment: ok thankyou RiggsFolly ,, i had some query in here please give me some review,, SELECT t.updateHistoryID,
t.updateTime
FROM web_historyupdate t INNER JOIN (
SELECT updateHistoryID, max(updateTime) as maxdate FROM web_historyupdate
    GROUP BY updateHistoryID
) tm ON t.updateHistoryID =tm.updateHistoryID AND t=tm.maxdate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL - How to select rows with the latest time for each date within the last 30 days from now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899148/mysql-how-to-select-rows-with-the-latest-time-for-each-date-within-the-last-30)

Comment: yes im looking for Maximum datetime per date

Comment: You might try `GROUP BY DATE( updateTime )`  as you want the max date time for each day and not for each ID

Comment: Why should I provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example for any SQL query question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: It seems you haven't understood what `GROUP BY` does. Your `GROUP BY updateHistoryID` makes no sense, as every row is in a group of its own when grouping by a unique ID. You want to group by the date instead to get the maximum datetime per date. Well, just as  RiggsFolly said :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the maximum datetime per date. As mentioned, "Maximum" translates to `MAX` in SQL and "per" transates to `GROUP BY`. One way to apply this to your data:

```
select *
from web_historyupdate
where updateTime in
(
  select max(updateTime)
  from web_historyupdate
  group by date(updateTime)
)
order by updateTime;
```

There exist of course other ways to do this. You could for instance select every row for which `NOT EXISTS` a row on the same day at a later time.